# Inserting middleware in Padrino

Tags: ruby, thin, padrino

I have a skeleton Padrino (0.10.7) project, with pretty much no code. I am trying to insert a middleware in boot.rb:

```
##
# Add your after (RE)load hooks here
#
Padrino.after_load do
    DataMapper.finalize
    Padrino.use MyClass      #Line (1) added by me
end

Padrino.load!
```

In MyClass,

```
class MyClass
    def initialize arg
    @arg = arg
    end
end
```

If I try to use thin server (1.5.x), I get this exception (only when I insert my middleware):

```
Uncaught exception: app required
```

Same works fine with builtin webrick.

Any idea on how to make it work with thin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, found it. Basically, you need to define the call (env) method too, otherwise it wont even start the server. This is what minimum is required from a middleware:

```
class MyClass
    def initialize app
        @app = app
    end
    def call env
        @app.call env
    end
end
```